# How to make an Image View round in Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

I have used the following method to make the image rounded, but the results are not the desired ones. I have shared my code and the result in the description below. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:{self.image1.setRounded()})
    
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

extension UIImageView {

func setRounded() {
    let radius = self.frame.width / 2
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Results :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make the image rounded, you have to make the height equal to the width. And then try:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setRounded() {
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height/2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

And call it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
override func viewDidLayouSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayouSubviews()
   image1.setRounded()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, now it's giving me a square image!

Comment: To make the image rounded, you have to make the height equal to the width.

Comment: Apart from the height and the width do I have to remove any other constraints?

Comment: Cause I have made the height and width equal but it still doesn't work for me!

Comment: Could you make sure they are constrained with the same height and width constants?